# SSRS cell expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Trying to add an expression to a cell in an SSRS table, I have a sql table with 4 columns: col1, col2, col3, col4.
The col4 has 4 possible values: val1, val2, val3, val4.

=IIF(Fields!col4.Value = "val4", Fields!col2, 0)

When I run my report, I just get 0 in the cell.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remember SSRS syntax is **case sensitive**. If col4 value is `VAL4` instead of `val4` your expression will return 0. For val1, val2 and val3 your expression will always return 0.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, three options:

1. You're a victim of SSRS's aggresive caching of dataset results; or
2. `Fields!col4.Value` is always actually "val4"; or
3. `Fields!col2.Value` is always 0.

(This is assuming that `Fields!col2` is a typo and it should be `Fields!col2.Value`.)

Comment: Yes, thats a typo.  Its Fields!col2.Value

Comment: Fields!col2.Value is not 0.  Fields!col4.Value is not always val4, as there are 4 possible values for col4.  How would I check about the aggressive caching?

Comment: Delete the .data file and reboot VS entirely.